# Can we rename cout, endl keyword in cpp?

Tags: c++

As typedef can give change names of types and define can make an alias for values and functions,
Is there any way to change the name of cout, endl etc???

Comment: `auto& cout_by_another_name = std::cout;` Not clear why you want that, but here it is.

Comment: @t.niese A reference will work with both. `using` only alises types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways to do that. In C++ sense, you could use `std::ostream`:

```
#include <iostream>
std::ostream& alias = std::cout;
```

Or, in a better manner, use reference to `auto` to let the compiler decide the correct type.

```
auto& print = std::cout;
```

**Some important notes:**

1. You can't create aliases of `std::cout`, `std::endl`, etc. with `using` statement.
2. Since `std::endl` is a template function and not a type, it can't be deduced using the reference to auto type.

---

OTOH, you can use `#define` statements (C like):

```
#include <iostream>
#define print std::cout <<
#define end   << std::endl
.
.
print "Hello world!" end;
```

Answer (score 4):

> Can we rename cout, endl keyword in cpp?

Neither `cout` nor `endl` are keywords in C++. They are names declared in `std` namespace of the standard library. Former is a variable and latter is a function template.

You cannot "rename" variables nor function templates any more than you can rename types, but like you can create an alias for types, you can essentially achieve the same for variables using a reference:

```
auto& some_name = std::cout;
```

For function templates, an option is to write a wrapper function template:

```
template<class CharT, class Traits>
auto&
endl_wrapper(std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& os)
{
    return std::endl(os);
}
```

---

Avoid obfuscating the program with unnecessary aliases.

Comment: This.  It's important to note that most of the C++ standard library is just prebuilt C++ code that you could have written yourself, and has no* magic. *A tiny amount of it is actually built into the language, namely these: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/freestanding