# Why does the type deduction for std::endl fails?

Tags: c++, c++14, auto, type-deduction

In the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

auto& print = std::cout; // Type deduction for std::cout works
auto& end = std::endl;   // But the std::endl is exception here

int main(void) {
  print << "Hello" << end;

  return 0;
}
```

The type deduction for `std::cout` takes place properly, but why doesn't it works for `std::endl`?

**Note:** Removing the reference to operator (ampersand) doesn't works either.

---

The VS Code says:

[image: Type deduction error screenshot]

And the compiler generates the following:

```
$ g++ -Wall -O3 -std=c++14 -o main main.cpp; ./main

main.cpp:4:18: error: unable to deduce 'auto&' from 'std::endl'
    4 | auto& end = std::endl;    // But the std::endl is exception here
      |                  ^~~~
main.cpp:4:18: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'auto'
```

Comment: You really shouldn't try to rename standard library constructs like that.

Comment: @NicolBolas I understand it. I was so confused when I saw it working with `std::cout` but not in case with `std::cin`. Searched about it, but doesn't seems I found something relevant about this problem.

Comment: Did you write this code based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63329779/)? Specifically, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63329879/65863), which shows the `auto& print = std::cout;` trick, but also says "*Since `std::endl` is a template function and not a type, **it can't be deduced using the reference to `auto` type**.*"

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, I wrote that as soon as I get understand the reason. And it was peculiar stuff that `std::endl` didn't work that time. I had no idea about it.

Comment: Most of the time you don't need `std::endl`. `auto end = '\n'` would work just as well (And you could just write `"Hello\n"`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we rename cout, endl keyword in cpp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63329779/can-we-rename-cout-endl-keyword-in-cpp)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::cout` is an object of a concrete type `std::ostream` (aka the `std::basic_ostream<char>` specialization), so `auto` can deduce its type.

`std::endl` is not an object at all, it is a template function (specifically, a stream manipulator taking a templated `std::basic_ostream` object as a parameter):

```cpp
template< class CharT, class Traits >
std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& endl( std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& os );
```

Being a template allows `std::endl` to work with output streams of different character types (`char`, `wchar_t`, etc), ie `std::cout` vs `std::wcout`, etc.

But, you are not providing any values for the template parameters to tell the compiler which specialization of `std::endl` you want to use, so `auto` can't deduce a concrete type for it, hence the error.

You would have to do something like this instead:

```cpp
auto& end = std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char>>;
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/ByctOS)

Comment: @RohanBari [templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates) is a very complex topic, there are whole chapters, and even whole books, on the subject. I strongly suggest you get yourself some [good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to read.